# Ajax loaded div, autopost back on loaded page doesn't work

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that runs a jquery onclick event. The event loads an an external .aspx file into a div. The page that's being loaded has a drop down list with an autopostback attribute that passes the selected item to a label.

Everything works fine except that the .aspx file that's being loaded will only post back once. After that no more autopostback. Here's my code

----- external.aspx ------

```
<script> 
protected void ddlPrices_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    lblPrice.Text = ddlPrices.SelectedValue.ToString();
   }
</script>


<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrices" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlPrices_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem>Basic</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Pro</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Platinum</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Baller!</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 

<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>          
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---- default.aspx ------

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("li#empNav1").click(function () {
$("div.subItem").load('external.aspx');
});
});
</script>

<ul class="nav-left">
<li id="empNav1" class="selected"><a href="#">Employer Overview</a></li>
<li id="empNav2"><a href="#">Why We're Better</a><span></span></li>
</ul>
<div class="subItem"></div>
```

As stated the div loads just fine, but external.aspx will only update lblPrice once. Then it no longer auto updates. Any help would be greatly appreciated specifics please....

Update I've tried putting the ddl and the postback into a control that external.aspx references and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `Server.Execute` to load the external page into the DIV in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event. Make sure to add `runat="server"` to the DIV though, or change the div to a Panel (which resolves to a DIV)

Comment: Specifics? How would load the div using OnSelectedIndexChange when the UL is client side markup?

Comment: You want to load the page into `subItem` when the selected index of `ddlPrices` changes right?

Comment: Right. So what kind of script could I use. My <UL> is not running at the server level. How I would perform a Server.Execute function from jquery?